# How to configure various node environments

Tags: node.js, variables, configuration, environment

I am trying to configure my environment variables for different environments. So far, I have defined the environment variables:

`app/config.json:`

```
    "development": {
        "PORT": 3000,
        "APP_SECRET_KEY": "asdf",
        "DB_NAME": "sadf",
        "DB_USER": "sadf",
        "DB_USER_PASSWORD": "asdf", 
        "DB_HOST": "asdf",
        "DB_PORT": 5432,
        "DB_SEARCHPATH": "asdf"

    },

    "test": {
        "PORT": 3000,
        "APP_SECRET_KEY": "fdas",
        "DB_NAME": "fdas",
        "DB_USER": "fdsa",
        "DB_USER_PASSWORD": "fdsa", 
        "DB_HOST": "fdsa",
        "DB_PORT": 5432,
        "DB_SEARCHPATH": "fdsa"
    }
}
```

After this, I'm not sure where/how to tell node to use the dev or test variables depending on the environment I want to run in. Can someone help or point me to a tutorial? I have yet to find a holistic tutorial on this..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Somethiong like this http://himanshu.gilani.info/blog/2012/09/26/bootstraping-a-node-dot-js-app-for-dev-slash-prod-environment/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I generally do something similar to this on app-boot to copy a dynamic config to the environment config:

```
var config = require('./config');
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

var envConfig = config[env];

// copy config to proceed.env
for(var key in config) {
   process.env[key] = config[key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So first thing first i would recommend you to change config files to js and  to import them like any other module this would allow you to add logic to your config. 
In this example i choose my env based on environment variable called NODE_ENV.

```
var config = function  () {
switch(process.env.NODE_ENV) {
case 'development': 
    return {...}
case 'test': 
    return {...}
....}
module.exports = config();
```

This way you don't have to repeat the logic of choosing environment each time.

Comment: You can use require on json files the same way that you can on js files. You get the entire object back.

Comment: I know that but you can't add logic inside json file. in your solution you will need to add another module of js or additional logic every time

Comment: But once it's setup, you can add additional config or environments to the json without the need for adding a new case to the switch statement.

Comment: each time you require config you will have to check for process.env.NODE_ENV instead just to have the right config i find it more important than add more different environments( I require more times my config files than adding environments) also i dislike to add my configs to the process.env but this is just personal taste